# Assertion in jmeter and its impact on result

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am very new to jmeter and have recently started working on it for API load test. 
Could someone please explain me why do we need to put assertion in load test, that should have been checked as part of functional test.
Also if I add any assertion as part of my load test it will have an impact on result (avg time, deviation, median etc) which is not correct.

Your thought

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of an assertion on a response would be to insure that you have actually reached the correct destination.

For example if under load you server sends back incomplete responses, or a valid page containing an error message you would never know it without an assertion.

There is always some overhead for processing the assertion, but unless it is performing an excessive number of tests it should be minimal. The assertion is performed on the load generator so if that component cannot handle the additional overhead then the assertions will not be your only concern.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Followup question if similarly I am using pre-processor and post-processor does that account in repsonse time?

Comment: It will not be counted toward your response time, but will use cpu on the load generator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use assertions, but you need to use it carefully. Ensure you use them when required, try to extract as less data as possible.
Follow [JMeter tuning tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips):

- Use Response Assertion or Size assertion, but avoid XML Assertion,
  XML Schema Assertion and XPath Assertion
- Use Regular Expression Extractor, but avoid XPath Extractor when possible

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Followup question:
if similarly I am using pre-processor and post-processor does that account in repsonse time?